# Jquery on image error not working for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to swap an image's src value if the image doesn't load:

```
$('.profile-pic').on('error', function() {
    $(this).prop('src', 'uploads/profile/default.png');
});
```

If there is a single element with an id of `profile-pic`, I can use the above code (swapping the selector) and it works fine. So why isn't this working for each of the `.profile-pic` elements on the page?

Comment: That should work absolutely fine. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Not doing anything at all? Show us your markup.

Comment: Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/py8qn3d9/ The issue must lie elsewhere in your code.

Comment: There are no errors in the console. It's simply not swapping the image for the default.png - rather, it leaves the original src in the element.

Comment: Is this code definitely being hit (use `debugger`)? Are you binding this event prior to the elements existing (i.e. are the profile pics loaded dynamically after this line of code)? The fact is that your code is fine, 100% fine, so the error is definitely somewhere else - you need to provide more context so we can find what that 'something else' is.

Comment: Ah, you are correct - the elements were being loaded dynamically, and hadn't arrived yet. So I put the code in a callback and it works fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this http://jsfiddle.net/buhr164g/4/

```
$(function(){
    var p ='http://localhost.com/sampleimage';
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        $("body").append('<img class="profile-pic" src="'+p+'_'+i+'.jpg"/>');
    }

    $(".profile-pic").error(function(){
    /* Do error processing */
    }).attr('src',"http://journal.appconnect.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/runner_small.gif");
});
```